# When is the multiplication of rectangular matrices an invertible matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $W\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times n }$ with $N>n$. Under which conditions is the matrix $S=W^T W$ invertible?

Comment: We have $\text{rank}(S) = \text{rank}(W)$ (why?). Thus $S$ invertible $\iff  \text{rank}(S) = n \iff \text{rank}(W) = n$

Comment: @Dylan Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ the matrix $A^\intercal A$ is called the *Gramian* of $A$. This is an extremely important construction!

**Fact 1.** $A^\intercal A$ is an $n\times n$ symmetric matrix

*Proof.* Exercise $\Box$

**Fact 2.** $\operatorname{rank}(A^\intercal A)=\operatorname{rank}(A)$

*Proof.* Note that $\boldsymbol{v}\in\operatorname{Null}(A)$ implies $A^\intercal A\boldsymbol{v}=A^\intercal\boldsymbol{O}=\boldsymbol{O}$ so $\operatorname{Null}(A)\subset\operatorname{Null}(A^\intercal A)$.

Next, suppose $\boldsymbol{v}\in\operatorname{Null}(A^\intercal A)$. Then
$$
\lVert A\boldsymbol{v}\rVert^2
= \langle A\boldsymbol{v}, A\boldsymbol{v}\rangle
= \langle\boldsymbol{v}, A^\intercal A\boldsymbol{v}\rangle
= \langle\boldsymbol{v}, \boldsymbol{O}\rangle
= 0
$$
It follows that $A\boldsymbol{v}=\boldsymbol{O}$, so $\operatorname{Null}(A^\intercal A)\subset\operatorname{Null}(A)$.

Our work above then demonstrates that $\operatorname{Null}(A)=\operatorname{Null}(A^\intercal A)$. Thus
$$\operatorname{rank}(A^\intercal A)=n-\dim\operatorname{Null}(A^\intercal A)=n-\operatorname{Null}(A)=\operatorname{rank}(A)\qquad\Box$$

This now gives a satisfactory answer to your question:

**Fact 3.** $A^\intercal A$ is invertible if and only if $A$ has full column rank.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer Brian!

Answer (score 1):

$S$ will be invertible if $W$ is injective.  Maybe not the best proof...

Suppose not ($W$ injective, $S$ not bijective).  Then there exists $x\neq0$ s.t. $Sx=0$ and $\langle Sx,y\rangle=\langle Wx,Wy\rangle=0$ for all $y$, in particular for $y=x$.  Hence $\|Wx\|=0$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you very much!